# problem evaluating parsed expression in for loops: assigning returned values to vectors in the global enviroment

Tags: r

I have created a function that takes in a vector of strings and evaluates each  if there is a 2 after said string:
This is a simplified example of the code:

```
eg1<-function(string){
  return(eval(parse(text = string)))
}
eg1("2*2")
eg2<-eg1("eg0*2")
eg3<-function(vector){
  x<-vector
  x2<-c()
  for(i in 1:(length(x)-1)){
    if(x[i+1]==1)x2[length(x2)+1]<-x[i]
    if(x[i+1]==2){
      result<-eg1(x[i])
      eval(parse(text = paste(
        x[i+2],"<<-",result
      )),envir = globalenv())
    }
  }
}
#########################################################################
eg0<-c(1,2,3)
#########################################################################
eg3(c(
  "2*2",1,"2*2",2,"two_plus_two","eg0*2",2,"eg0_multiplied_by_2"
))
two_plus_two
eg0_multiplied_by_2
eg2<-eg1("eg0*2")
eg2
```

As you can see, when I run  `eg2<-eg1("eg0*2")` the function eg1 does well in making eg2 a vector of length 3 (as is the length of eg0).
The problem I cant solve is that, when inside the function eg3, the object created is just of length one, as if it where making`eg2<-eg1("eg0*2")[3]` **(the last value)**
What I want is that the object created in the enviroment with the function eg3, conserve the orginal length of the returned expression that whould be  `eg2<-eg1("eg0*2")`.
Best regards.

Comment: What is the purpose of this approach, why are conventional methods not suitable? It seems rather hard-to-read approach to assign multiple new variables. An alternative here could be a 2 liner: `library(zeallot) c(two_plus_two, eg0_multiplied_by_2) %<-% list(2+2, eg0*2)`

Comment: Well, I simplified all the functions in an attempt to make them simpler to be read, but in the actual code, the function eg1 does a series of edits of the string before it evaluates them as expressions. The strings them selves need to be edited before being evaluated and then return an answer.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are trying to do here. What exactly is the desired output? Look at the result of `paste("myvar", "<<-", 1:3)`. That's not the right way to build assignment expressions. This seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) in that we are trying to fix your solution rather than really solve the problem. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this code.

Comment: well thanks @MrFlick it seems that I didn't noticed that paste worked that way with vectors and I'm pretty sure that that is the root of the problem. I'll get to try it out when I get back to work tomorrow

Comment: Better yet, use assign() rather than parsing an assignment expression.

Comment: You should not use `eval(parse())`. You can compute on the language in R (but I seriously doubt that you actually need to). You also shouldn't use `<<-` to assign into the global environment. Functions with such side effects are extremely bad practice and will sooner or later bite you in the behind.

Comment: yeah @MrFlick your right I think the solution would be to change `eval(parse(text = paste(
        x[i+2],"<<-",result
      )),envir = globalenv())`
with
`assign(x[i+2],result, envir = globalenv())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indeed, the as @MrFlick mentioned the problem is that using paste with a vector returns a vector of the same length:

```
paste("myvar", "<<-", 1:3)
```

[1] "myvar <<- 1" "myvar <<- 2"
[3] "myvar <<- 3"

So thats why the value assigned at the end was

```
eg2<-eg1("eg0*2")[3]
```

So then, the working solution would be:

```
eg1<-function(string){
  return(eval(parse(text = string)))
}
eg3<-function(vector){
  x<-vector
  x2<-c()
  for(i in 1:(length(x)-1)){
    if(x[i+1]==1)x2[length(x2)+1]<-x[i]
    if(x[i+1]==2){
      result<-eg1(x[i])
      assign(x[i+2],result, envir = globalenv())#Fixed
    }
  }
}
#########################################################################
#########################################################################
eg0<-c(1,2,3)
eg3(c(
  "2*2",1,"2*2",2,"two_plus_two","eg0*2",2,"eg0_multiplied_by_2"
))
two_plus_two
[1] 4
eg0_multiplied_by_2
[1] 2 4 6
```